# How to determine if this is true or false?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$$\exists x \in X, (P(x) \to Q(x))\hspace{0.2cm} \iff (\exists x \in X, P(x))\to (\exists x \in X, Q(x))$$

$$\forall x \in X, (P(x) \to Q(x))\hspace{0.2cm} \iff (\forall x \in X, P(x))\to (\forall x \in X, Q(x))$$

Really don't know where to start

Comment: Maybe try some basic examples first. With implications like $P\rightarrow Q$ where $P$ is always false so our implication is vacuous.

Comment: @JackDavies I kind figure out that exists statement is false. There is could one direction true but another direction false. However, when comes to for all statement, I don't know how to try examples.

Comment: Hint: To get you started, assume the LHS of the biconditional is true, then assume the antecedent of conditional on the RHS is true, then prove $\exists x\in X : Q(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Implication Equivalence and the Laws of Negation and Distribution of Quantifiers.

$$\begin{align}
 & \exists x \in X: (P(x) \to Q(x))
\\[1ex] \iff & \exists x\in X : (\neg P(x)\vee Q(x))
& \text{Implication Equivalence}
\\[1ex] \iff & (\exists x\in X: \neg P(x)) \vee (\exists x\in X:Q(x))
& \text{Distribution: Existential over Disjunction}
\\[1ex] \iff & \neg(\forall x \in X: P(x))\vee (\exists x \in X: Q(x))
& \text{Universal Negation}
\\[1ex] \iff & (\color{red}{\forall} x \in X:P(x))\to (\exists x\in X: Q(x))
& \text{Implication Equivalence}
\end{align}$$

So we must conclude that your given equivalence is not generally true.

---

For the other one, beware that the Distribution of Universal over Disjunction itself is not an equivalence.

Comment: A little confusion. When you say the Distribution of Universal over Disjunction itself is not an equivalence. it means that $\forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x))$ is not equivalent to $(\forall x P(x) \lor \forall x  Q(x) )$ Comes to the second statement. The left side is ($\forall x,  \neg P(x) \lor Q(x))$, the right side is $(\exists x , \neg P(x)) \lor (\forall x, Q(x))$. Can this be directly saied that two side are not equivalent? Because the right side it's not $(\forall x P(x) \lor \forall x  Q(x) )$. But there is an exists quantifier

Answer (score 1):

In general, to show that : $\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$, we have to provide a proof in some *proof system*.

To show instead that  $\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$ does not hold, we have to provide a suitable counter-example to one of the conditionals : $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$, $\psi \rightarrow \varphi$.

---

For :

> $∀x(P(x) → Q(x)) \leftrightarrow (∀xP(x) → ∀xQ(x))$

we can provide a counter-example showing that :

> $(∀xP(x) → ∀xQ(x)) \rightarrow ∀x(P(x) → Q(x))$

does not hold.

Consider an interpretation with domain the set $X = \{ 0,1 \}$ and consider as $P(x)$ the formula $(x = 0)$ and as $Q(x)$ the formula $(x > 0)$.

We have that :

$∀x(x = 0) → ∀x(x > 0)$

is *true* in $X$, because both the antecedent and the consequent are *false*.

Consider now :

$∀x[(x = 0) → (x > 0)]$;

choosing $0$ as value for $x$, we have that $(0 = 0) → (0 > 0)$ is *false* (antecedent *true*, while consequent *false*) and thus it is *false* that $(x = 0) → (x > 0)$ is *true* for any value of $x$.

Thus $∀x[(x = 0) → (x > 0)]$ is *false* in $X$.

In conclusion, we have found an interpretation such that $∀xP(x) → ∀xQ(x)$ is *true* and $∀x(P(x) → Q(x))$ is *false*, i.e. :

> > $∀xP(x) → ∀xQ(x) \nvDash ∀x(P(x) → Q(x))$,

and thus :

> $\nvDash (∀xP(x) → ∀xQ(x)) \rightarrow ∀x(P(x) → Q(x))$.

---

The same interpretation can be used to show that :

> $∃x(P(x) → Q(x)) \nvDash ∃xP(x) → ∃xQ(x)$.

Consider now as $P(x)$ the formula $(x > 0)$ and as $Q(x)$ the formula $(x < 0)$.

Now we have that $(x > 0) \rightarrow (x < 0)$ is *true* for $0$ as value of $x$, and thus $∃x[(x > 0) \rightarrow (x < 0)]$ is *true* in $X$.

But $∃x(x > 0)$ is *true* while $∃x(x < 0)$ is *false*, and thus $∃x(x > 0) \rightarrow   ∃x(x < 0)$ is *false*.

Answer (score 0):

To try examples with these sentences, you have two predicates $P$ and $Q$.  Each member of $X$ can satisfy $P(x)$ or not and (separately) satisfy $Q(x)$ or not.  You can let $X$ have four members.  Each one will have one of the four possible truth values for $P$ and $Q$.  For example, one of them will have $P(x)$ true and $Q(x)$ false.  Now test each sentence for a tautology.  If one fails in this case you are done.  If a sentence passes, you need to think about whether deleting some element of $X$ will render it false.

Comment: So I can arbitrarily set P(x) and Q(x) to be false or true? It's totally depend on me?

Comment: There are only four possibilities, so the $X$ I proposed covers them all.  But whoever asserted these claims that they work for *all* $X$, so if you find one where they don't work you have what you need.  I suggested some (ways I believe are) productive ways to think about an $X$ to make them fail.

Comment: I have workout that exists statement is false, only one direction is true. But for for all statement. It seems that regardless of quantifies, both statements are false. But somehow my intuition tells me that second one true

Comment: Whoever has asserted these to you has claimed they are true for all $X$.  If you find any $X$ where they are false, you are done. I suggested a way to find some $X$'s that will be challenging.  In particular, there will only be $2^{(2^2)}=16\ \ X$'s that matter.  That is not so many, you can check them all.